# Bootstrap Toggle switch not working when loaded by ajax and make a call of event for 2 times

Tags: jquery, ajax

[image]

I'm loading this toggle html through ajax and loading this switch in page and try to make enable/disable status of the product. But when i call it through ajax it is not working.

Comment: please check following..i have faced same problem but i solved as below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the switch code after successful response form the ajax.

All the event binding to that switch must be done after the ajax response because you are dynamically adding content so for that reason you need to reinitialize all the stuff for that switch

Comment: facing same issue here, can you please explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem about a week ago.I solved problem as below.Hope following code helps you a lot.

Test.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript"     src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="classes/commons/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 


  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="audio_alarm.php" method="post"> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled" checked>
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="heading"></div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="body"></div>
  </div>
    <div></div>
    <script>
      $('#toggle').change(function(){
        var mode= $(this).prop('checked');
        // // submit the form 
        // $(#myForm).ajaxSubmit(); 
        // // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
        // return false; 
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          dataType:'JSON',
          url:'audio_alarm.php',
          data:{mode:mode},
          success:function(data)
          {
            var data=eval(data);
            message=data.message;
            success=data.success;
            $("#heading").html(success);
            $("#body").html(message);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And

audio_alarm.php

```
<?php

$mode=$_POST['mode'];

if ($mode=='true') //mode is true when button is enabled 
{
    //Retrive the values from database you want and send using json_encode
    //example
    $message='Hey my button is enableed!!';
    $success='Enabled';
    echo json_encode(array('message'=>$message,'$success'=>$success));
}

else if ($mode=='false')  //mode is false when button is disabled
{
    //Retrive the values from database you want and send using json_encode
    //example
    $message='Hey my button is disable!!';
    $success='Disabled';
    echo json_encode(array('message'=>$message,'success'=>$success));

} 
 ?>
```